# Graphing $f(2-x)$

Tags: functions, linear-transformations, solution-verification, graphing-functions, transformation

Sorry for this very trivial question, but I've become slightly confused by this question. Consider a graph
$y=f(x)$. How would I draw the graph $y=f(2-x)$?

It seems to me that as this is obviously equal to $y=f(-(x-2))$ this should represent the graph being translated $2$ units in the positve $x$ direction and then reflected in the $y$ axis.

Is that true? It doesn't seem to be from the graphs I have plotted using Desmos. If not, please explain why it is incorrect.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
I have now slept over my problem and I believe that it lies in the following statement I have been led to believe in class:

> The graph of $f(\text{Blah}+a)$ is ALWAYS  a translation of $a$ units of the graph $f(\text{Blah})$ in the negative direction.

More specifically, I thought that the as graph of $f(x+a)$ is a translation of $a$ units of the graph $f(x)$ in the negative direction, then the graph of $f(-x+a)$ is a translation of $a$ units of the graph $f(-x)$ in the negative direction as well. After thinking it over logically however, I now think this is wrong.

This is my reasoning:

Consider $y=f(x+a)$. For a given $y$ value on the $y=f(x+a)$ graph, the $x$ value needed for it must be $a$ smaller than the $x$ value needed if it was just the function $y=f(x)$; hence the graph $y=f(x+a)$ must be the graph of $y=f(x)$ but shifted $a$ units to the negative $x$ direction.

But, if we consider $y=f(-x+a)$: For a given $y$ value on the $y=f(-x+a)$ graph, the $x$ value needed for it must be $a$ **bigger** than the $x$ value needed if it was just the function $y=f(-x)$; hence the graph $y=f(-x+a)$ must be the graph of $y=f(-x)$ but shifted $a$ units to the **positive** $x$ direction.

Is my reasoning correct now?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Replace every instance of $x$ with $2-x$ to see algebraically what $f(2-x)$ looks like

Comment: @Travis I know I could do that, but graphically I can't see how that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed equal to $f(-(x-2))$, but your interpretation of the latter is incorrect.

You identified the correct operations:

1. Translate 2 units in the positive $x$ direction (replace $x$ with $x-2$).
2. Reflect in the $y$ axis (replace $x$ with $-x$).

But what order do you have to do these in to get $f(-(x-2))$?

---

The reasoning added in [revision 2 of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3893206/revisions), a few minutes before this edit to my answer, is correct.

Comment: Oh, I think i get it now! Whenever we have a reflection in the $y$ axis, do we only make the $x$ negative and nothing else? Ie not make everything inside the brackets of $f()$ negative?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Correct!

Comment: Now I'm confused for a different reason. If so, shouldn't it be a reflection in the $y$ axis first and then a translation by $2$ units in the NEGATIVE direction?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Please edit the question to show your working here. Then we can help you more.

Comment: Please see my edit now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 4):

Denote $g(x)=f(2-x)$ and set $x'=2-x$. What you want is drawing the graph of $g$. Now the points $x$ and $x'$ are symmetric (on the $x$-axis) w.r.t. the point $1$ since $\frac{x+x'}2=1$, and $g(x)=f(x')$. Therefore the graph of $g$ is the symmetric of the graph of $f\,$ w.r.t.  the line $x=1$.

Comment: Please see my edit. Btw what does w.r.t stand for?

Comment: `w.r.t.`= ‘with respect to’.

Comment: I see , thanks.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by symmetric? Symmetrical?

Comment: Better wording: The graph of $g$ is the reflection of the graph of $f$ in the line $x = 1$. Also, can you explain how you determined that?

Comment: @BrianDrake: quite simple – the corresponding points on the graphs of $g$ and $f$ oare $(x, f(x')$ and $(x',f(x')$ respectively, i.e. same ordinates and symmetrical abscissæ.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, obviously. That is the whole point of defining $x'$ this way. (By the way, you are missing closing brackets.) But how did you determine that $x$ and $x'$ are symmetric w.r.t. $1$?

Comment: The midpoint of $x$ and $2-x$ is $1$.

Comment: @Bernard I think that ought to be in the answer.

Comment: Doesn't any high-shool student know that the symmetrical of $x$ w.r.t. to the number $a$ is $2a-x$?

Comment: @Bernard I'm sorry, but I've never come across the term symmetric in maths before, probably because I live and go to high school in England. Perhaps some of the terms or topics covered here are different to the ones covered in schools where you live.

Comment: OH I finally see what you mean now!!!! Thanks so much, that is an excellent answer!!!!

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If you know the graph of the curve whose equation is $ y=f(x) $, the graph of $ y=f(-x) $ is the symetric with respect to $ Oy$ axis.

if you know the graph of $ y =g(x)$ , the graph of $ y=g(x-a) $ is got by the translation of vector $ (a,0)$.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is really about the order of applying the different trasformations.

Comment: $ f(-(x-2))$ implies translation and then symetry.

Comment: Please see edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Label the point $x=0$ as $a$ and $x=2$ as $b$. Now exchange $a,b$.

[image]